# How can I split up a Git commit buried in history?

Tags: git, split, commit, revision-history

I flubbed up my history and want to do some changes to it. Problem is, I have a commit with two unrelated changes, and this commit is surrounded by some other changes in my local (non-pushed) history.

I want to split up this commit before I push it out, but most of the guides I'm seeing have to do with splitting up your most recent commit, or uncommitted local changes. Is it feasible to do this to a commit that is buried in history a bit, without having to "re-do" my commits since then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a commit of a copy+modify into a copy commit and a modify commit using git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118042/split-a-commit-of-a-copymodify-into-a-copy-commit-and-a-modify-commit-using-git)

Answer (score 461, accepted):

There is a guide to splitting commits [in the rebase manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase.html#_splitting_commits). The quick summary is:

- Perform an interactive rebase including the target commit (e.g. `git rebase -i <commit-to-split>^ branch`) and mark it to be edited.
- When the rebase reaches that commit, use `git reset HEAD^` to reset to before the commit, but keep your work tree intact.
- Incrementally add changes and commit them, making as many commits as desired. `add -p` can be useful to add only some of the changes in a given file. Use [`commit -c ORIG_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/367456) if you want to re-use the original commit message for a certain commit.
- If you want to test what you're committing (good idea!) use `git stash` to hide away the part you haven't committed (or `stash --keep-index` before you even commit it), test, then `git stash pop` to return the rest to the work tree. Keep making commits until you get all modifications committed, i.e. have a clean work tree.
- Run `git rebase --continue` to proceed applying the commits after the now-split commit.

Comment: ... but don't any of it if you already pushed the history since the commit to split.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I omitted my usual "potentially dangerous; see 'recovering from upstream rebase'" boilerplate because the OP explicitly said he hadn't pushed this history.

Comment: and you made a perfect read. I was trying to avoid the 'boilerplate' when I specified it wasn't shared history yet :) In any regard, I have had success with your suggestion. It is a big pain to do this stuff after the fact though. I've learned a lesson here, and that is to make sure the commits are put in correctly to begin with!

Comment: The first step may be better stated as `git rebase -i <sha1_of_the_commit_to_split>^ branch`. And `git gui` is a nice tool for the splitting task, which can be used to add different parts of a file into different commits.

Comment: @QiangXu: The first is a reasonable suggestion. The second is exactly why I suggested `git add -p`, which can do more than `git gui` can in this department (notably editing hunks, staging everything starting from the current hunk, and searching for hunks by regex).

Comment: I wish `rebase -i` had a command to automate the `reset HEAD^` step. Perhaps a command called `review` or `re-edit`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to do it with [Magit](https://magit.vc/).

Say commit ed417ae is the one you want to change; it contains two unrelated changes and is buried under one or more commits. Hit `ll` to show the log, and navigate to ed417ae:

[image: initial log]

Then hit `r` to open the rebase popup

[image: rebase popup]

and `m` to modify the commit at point.

Notice how the `@` there is now on the commit you want to split – that means HEAD is now at that commit:

[image: modifying a commit]

We want to move HEAD to the parent, so navigate to the parent (47e18b3) and hit `x` (`magit-reset-quickly`, bound to `o` if you're using `evil-magit`) and enter to say "yes I meant commit at point". Your log should now look like:

[image: log after resetting]

Now, hit `q` to go to the regular Magit status, then use the regular unstage `u` command to unstage what doesn't go in the first commit, commit `c` the rest as usual, then `s`tage and `c`ommit what goes in the second commit, and when done: hit `r` to open the rebase popup

[image: rebase popup]

and another `r` to continue, and you're done! `ll` now shows:

[image: all done log]

Answer (score 1):

To split a commit `<commit>` and add the **new commit before this one**, and save the author date of `<commit>`, — the steps are following:

1. Edit the commit **before** `<commit>`

   ```
   git rebase -i <commit>^^
   ```

   NB: perhaps it will be also needed to edit `<commit>` as well.
2. Cherry pick `<commit>` into the index

   ```
   git cherry-pick -n <commit>
   ```
3. Interactively reset unneeded changes from the index and reset the working tree

   ```
   git reset -p && git checkout-index -f -a
   ```

   As alternative, just stash unneeded changes interactively: `git stash push -p -m "tmp other changes"`
4. Make other changes (if any) and create the new commit

   ```
   git commit -m "upd something" .
   ```

   Optionally, repeat the items 2-4 to add more intermediate commits.
5. Continue rebasing

   ```
   git rebase --continue
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There's a faster version if you only want to extract content from just one file. It's faster because the interactive rebase is not actually interactive anymore (and it's of course even faster if you want to extract from the last commit, then no need to rebase at all)

1. Use your editor and delete the lines you want to extract from `the_file`. Close `the_file`. That's the only edition you need, all the rest is just git commands.
2. Stage that deletion in the index:

   ```
   git  add  the_file
   ```
3. Restore the lines you just deleted back into the file *without affecting the index*!

   ```
   git show HEAD:./the_file > the_file
   ```
4. "SHA1" is the commit you want to extract the lines from:

   ```
   git commit -m 'fixup! SHA1'
   ```
5. Create the second, brand new commit with the content to extract restored by step 3:

   ```
   git commit -m 'second and new commit' the_file
   ```
6. Don't edit, don't stop/continue - just accept everything:

   ```
   git rebase --autosquash -i SHA1~1
   ```

Of course even faster when the commit to extract from is the last commit:

```
4. git commit -C HEAD --amend
5. git commit -m 'second and new commit' thefile
6. no rebase, nothing
```

If you use `magit` then step 4, 5 and 6 are a single action: Commit, instant Fixup

Answer (score 0):

Manually correcting the history via cherry picking can also work for some cases.

I perfer to use my git GUI (instead of the command line), my problematic commit was only 3 commits down, I haven't yet pushed any, and the following ones weren't exactly tidy either, so I opted for completely reconstructing all of them by cherry-picking, and it was faster than using the interactive rebase edits via the command line, but similar in approach.

Here's how I did it in my favorite git GUI (I personally use SourceTree):

1. Create a **tag** on the current state so that it isn't lost.
2. Now **move** your actual local **branch pointer** to the messy commit.
3. **Reset (mixed) to the previous one**, so that the files from the commit in (2) are kept.
4. You can now **split the commit in two** or more by staging files that are needed and commiting with the correct message, until there's no unstaged files left.
5. **Cherry pick** the next commit in line (from the history you've tagged). You do this by right clicking the desired commit and choosing "cherry pick". Goto (4), do until no more unaccounted commits left.
6. Don't worry if as a result you have some commits that would be best squashed into one. You can squash them with an optional **interactive rebase** in GUI. It's as simple right-clicking the commit before the mess & clicking "Interactive rebase" then dragging commits onto each other to squash (fix the commit message to keep it simple), or move them up or down as desired.
7. **Remove the tag** created in (1).

Answer (score -2):

If you haven't pushed yet, just use `git rebase`. Even better, use `git rebase -i` to move commits around interactively. You can move the offending commit to the front, then split it up as you like and move the patches back (if needed).

Comment: There's no need to move it anywhere. Split it where it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me because some of the history after the commit is dependent on it, so I'm a little restricted. However, this would have been my first choice.

Comment: @Ben: that's okay - the commits afterwards won't need to change at all (assuming you keep all the changes, rather than throwing some of them away). More information here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440050/how-to-split-last-commit-into-two-in-git