# How do I keep the commit message when editing commits via git rebase --interactive?

Tags: git

I'm currently in the midst of a  `git rebase --interactive` session, where I'm editing a commit. I'm proceeding as suggested by [How can I split up a Git commit buried in history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307095/git-how-to-split-up-a-commit-buried-in-history) i.e. I ran `git reset HEAD^` and did my modifications.
Now I want rebase to continue, which requires me to commit my changes. I'd like to modify my old commit message, but the problem is, if I run `git commit --amend`, I'm given the commit message of the commit *before* the one I'm actually modifiying -- and I certainly don't want to merge my changes into that commit.

So how do I retrieve my old commit message for the commit I'm working on now?

Comment: git commit --amend should display the message of the commit you're editing (I just tried), there must be something wrong here

Comment: @CharlesB Did you try it within a workflow as described, ie after `git rebase --interactive`, `git reset HEAD^`, some modifications, and adding files back to the index?

Comment: OK, not sure if it what you want but the proposed commit message is set to `HEAD^`'s one. It perfectly makes sense to me since it is the one you want to split

Comment: the commit you marked for editing is the child of the one you want to split

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure I marked the right commit for editing, and resetting the index with `git reset HEAD^` really unstaged the changes I wanted to work on... (I'm not actually trying to split that commit, but just modifying some of the changes it introduces.)

Comment: OK, I think I can answer

Comment: @BernhardReiter please update your question to make it clear that you just want to edit the commit, not split it, and also if any of the solutions below fixed your problem, it would be helpful to other people in the future if you accepted it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While [CharlesB's solution is correct and probably easier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11343/charlesb), the reason that the original poster is seeing the commit message ***before*** the commit he wants to edit is because he's using the `--amend` flag of `git commit`, which modifies ***the previous*** commit.

Instead of using `--amend` to commit your changes, just use `git commit` without the flag, which won't touch the previous commit. You can also pass in an option to reuse the commit message from the commit that you reset using `git reset head^`:

```bash
git commit --reuse-message=HEAD@{1}

# Or use -C, which is the same thing, but shorter:
git commit -C HEAD@{1}
```

`HEAD@{1}` points to the commit you were at before you did `git reset head^`. You can also just pass in the sha id for that commit directly.

From [the `git commit` docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

> ```
> -C <commit>
> --reuse-message=<commit>
> ```
>
> Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the commit.

Of course, like I said, CharlesB's solution is simpler, since if you don't do the first `git reset head^`, you can just make changes and amend the commit you're trying to modify directly, and you automatically get the previous commit message when you do `git commit --amend`, you don't have to pass in the commit sha for it.

Comment: does a lower case `head` actually work here? i had to use the fully capitalized version.

Comment: @milkypostman it actually depends on your OS and shell environment, msysgit and OS X seem to be okay with lower-case head, but Unix environments will probably only accept upper-case `HEAD`.

Comment: `HEAD` can be substituted for `@` in all git versions for the last few years, e.g. `HEAD@{1}` becomes `@{1}`, `HEAD~` becomes `@~`.  Saves some typing.

Comment: @user456814 I suspect `head` works if your file system is case-insensitive; it is probably referring to the `.git/HEAD` file in your repo.  As I've mentioned above though, if your git version is vaguely recent you can use `@` instead of `head` or `HEAD`.

Answer (score 5):

Why follow instructions on commit splitting [if you don't want it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832722/how-do-i-keep-the-commit-message-when-editing-commits-via-git-rebase-interacti#comment14104282_10832722)?

You don't reset to `HEAD^`, this applies only when splitting commits. Just mark the commit for editing in `rebase -i`, make your changes, `commit --amend` and `rebase --continue`.

Comment: Couldn't you actually do `git reset head^`, but instead of using `git commit --amend`, just use `git commit`, then `rebase --continue`? Same result, wouldn't it be?

Comment: I find it hard to understand, how can one guess what is `HEAD^` in the middle of an interactive rebase? amending a commit is simple and clear

Comment: No need to guess, `git log --graph --oneline` makes it perfectly clear what `head^` is, even during `rebase -i`. But I agree, simply amending the commit is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I have another answer that seems to be more fool-proof, though undocumented.

```
$ git reset HEAD^
$ git add ...               # stage the first part of your split
$ git commit -m 'part one'
$ git commit -a -F $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/rebase-merge/message
```

Comment: Again, the original poster doesn't want to split his commit, so making two commits is not the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted some examples in [git-commit(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) and [git-reset(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html):

```
$ git reset HEAD^
$ git add ...                 # stage the first part of your split
$ git commit -m 'part one'
$ git commit -a -c ORIG_HEAD  # start with the earlier commit message
```

If you're worried about doing something that might change `ORIG_HEAD`, you could instead do:

```
$ SAVED=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
$ git reset HEAD^
...
$ git commit -a -c $SAVED   # start with the earlier commit message
```

Comment: The part of your answer that uses `commit` without the `--amend` flag is correct. However, as the original poster states in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832722/how-do-i-keep-the-commit-message-when-editing-commits-via-git-rebase-interacti#comment14104282_10832722), he's not trying to split his commit, so making two separate commits is not the right solution.

Comment: Also, in your answer, `ORIG_HEAD` points to ***the first commit*** that the original poster was on before he started rebasing. If he's editing a commit that's an ancestor of `ORIG_HEAD`, then `ORIG_HEAD` ***will not contain the original message*** for the ancestor, in which case that part of your solution will be incorrect.

Comment: I've answered the question as it is written, which I think is fair.  Original poster is free to edit it. :-)  And thanks for the correction--`ORIG_HEAD` is assuming the `git reset HEAD^` has already happened, which is not what I wrote.  Fixed now.

Comment: I had meant to take another look at this a long while back. I'm not sure anything I mentioned to you in my comments was correct, so your answer may have been just fine as it was.