# View older failed commit messages

Tags: git

If a git commit fails, the commit message can be recovered from the `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file. This file gets overwritten by the last commit message that is attempted. Is there a way to view a failed commit message that was used before the last one?

Answer (score 4):

Not natively with Git. You would have to setup an external process which:

- would detect any changes in that file
- save it with a differ name

But you would review those past commit messages on your own.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17643418/6309) mentions the possibility to reuse past commit message with:

```
git commit --reuse-message=head@{1}
```

That isn't exactly what you want (in term of message of "past failed commits", but is the only native git way I know of using past commit messages.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought of this...Its just a little too tedious because would i not end up saving every commit message that was attempted, not just the ones that failed?