# Use only one commit comment in git rebase -i

Tags: git

When I'm doing git rebase -i, I have an option to squash my commits into one.

What I normally do is change the 1st commit message and squash the rest of the commits.

After that I'm presented with a screen that tells me to:

**Please enter the commit message for your changes.**

Is there a way to use only the one commit message I decided in the previous step?

Comment: If your goal is to edit the message only once, why don't you just squash in the rebase then do that edit at the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep the commit message when editing commits via git rebase --interactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832722/how-do-i-keep-the-commit-message-when-editing-commits-via-git-rebase-interacti)

Answer (score 3):

When the editor opens, it should give you a comment describing the available commands which (among other things) contains:

```
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
```

It sounds like you just want to use `f` to "fixup" the commit.

In other words, in the editor, don't change the first column of the commit you wish to keep (or perhaps change it to `r`), and change the first column of the commits you wish to squash to `f`.