# Pull-Request for only certain files/commits

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

I have a repository that is forked from [GitHub](http://www.github.com/) that has a few modifications made to it. However, in a certain commit, a few files were changed that I want to submit a pull-request for, leaving the other modified files out of the request.

Do pull requests merge *all* commits, or do I need to do something special to isolate this commit?

Comment: This may be related: [How to git-cherry-pick only changes to certain files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5717026)

Comment: @jww Years later and `git cherry-pick` has become absolutely invaluable. Should have picked up on it a lot sooner than I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to git-cherry-pick only changes to certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A pull request being made of whole commits, you need to split this commit into two separate commits one containing the change to put in the pull request, and the other holding the other changes. To do this you need `git rebase -i`, see for example [How can I split up a Git commit buried in history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4307095/11343) for a good explanation on how to do it.

Once you have split  the commit, move the ones you want to include into a topic branch, see for example [How to move certain commits to another branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2369426/11343), but it depends if the commits that make your pull request are sequential.

Then finally you can push to Github and create the pull request from your topic branch.

Comment: For the record, `git cherry-pick` is an invaluable tool.

Comment: I see this is the accepted answer; but where, exactly, are the steps to perform so one can take changes to one file in a pull request that modifies multiple files?

Comment: What happens when you are the person merging the request, and not making the request? This tool is so lame...

Comment: @jww Then you ask the pull request author to rebase on top of master and only include the specific changes. :)

Answer (score 18):

Pull requests merge branches. So if you want to isolate some things for a pull request, best is to put those changes in a separate branch.

Advantage is that you can change the pull request by pushing new changes to that branch (even push -f if you need to change already pushed commits).

Comment: Given I already made the changes in one branch, how would you achieve this?