# How do I partially git cherry-pick without ruining a future merge?

Tags: git

I need to bring some bugfixes that were made to the `develop` branch into `master`. I'd like file `A` to be identical in `develop` and `master`.

Ordinarily, I would `git cherry-pick` the commits that affect `A`, but some of those commits also affect files `B` and `C`, where `B` is a file that exists in `master` but I don't want to change yet, and `C` is a file that does not yet exist in `master`.

When the next release is made at some point in the future, `develop` will be merged into `master`. If I `git cherry-pick -n` the commits I want now, I'll have to unstage changes to `B`, and resolve conflicts for the nonexistent `C` before committing. When the real merge from `develop` into `master` happens, I will want the changes to `B` and `C`, but I won't actually get them, since I already messed with those changes during the `cherry-pick`, right?

What should I do instead? If I `git checkout <latest_commit_hash> A`, won't that also cause a nasty merge conflict in the future?

Comment: I think you can create `temp` branch from master, cherry-peak commits from `develop` (or just copy files you need), than merge `temp` and `master`. But I am not sure.

Comment: You could also consider creating a patch, though that's a more advanced technique. Here's a brief tutorial: http://makandracards.com/makandra/2521-git-how-to-create-and-apply-patches

Answer (score 3):

In general avoid `git cherry-pick` if those branches are merged at any time in the future.

It seems to me that `git rebase` could actually be helping if the development branch is local and not publicly visible. If other people have seen your changes and those commits have different parents you cannot avoid a merge.

assume you have *n* commits after mainline in development and you have *m1,m2,m3* commits in *n* that you want to share with mainline.

if you do:

```
git checkout development # go to development branch
git rebase -i mainline   # reorder all commits in development
```

you will get an editor window that shows you one commit per line. if you put the commits of *m1,m2,m3* to the top of the line and choose `edit` (instead of `pick`) `git` will reorder your commits as you requested (top commit oldest and the bottom one newest) and it will halt before each commit marked as edit.

you can then do:

```
git add file1
git commit              # commit only file1
git commit -a           # commit the rest
git rebase --continue   # continue rebasing
```

you can then rebase another time to move the unwanted commits further up in your change history. if you are happy with your log (i.e.: all your commits you need in mainline are on top of changes in mainline and nothing else; hence you can merge doing a fast forward) you pick the furthest commit you want to have from your development branch (by SHA) and merge that.

```
git checkout mainline
git log development   # assume acf123 is the last commit you want
git merge acf123      # fast forward to the right commit
```

see also:

- [How can I split up a Git commit buried in history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307095/how-can-i-split-up-a-git-commit-buried-in-history)
- http://blog.dennisrobinson.name/reorder-commits-with-git/

Answer (score 1):

> If I git checkout develop -- A, won't that also cause a nasty merge conflict in the future?

No, not by itself it won't. Merge works by comparing each tip against the merge base and then comparing the two sets of changes. If both branches make the same changes, there's no conflict.

*Other* changes, on either branch, to or too near to lines changed in common on both branches, can appear as conflicts. The way to forestall those is to give git an accurate merge base by recording a merge from the common content.

```
# merging master and develop, but there are common changes and 
# also changes that conflict only with those common changes.
# supply git's merge with the common changes as part of the base,
# so it will see that it needs to resolve only those other changes

# check out the current merge base
git checkout $(git merge-base master develop)

# make the changes you're merging
git checkout develop -- file_A
git commit -m "cherrypicking file_A as of develop @ $(git rev-parse develop)"

# (for ensuite)
base=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

# record that both branches have those changes
git checkout develop
git merge -s ours $base -m "recording common content from previous cherry-picks"

git checkout master
git merge -s ours $base -m "recording common content from previous cherry-picks"

# and now this merge will get an accurate base:
git merge develop
```

Now: the only effect of those `$base` merges is to record the common content as ancestral to both branch tips, giving the merge from `develop` to `master` an accurate base from which to resolve the other changes.

The new commit gets history back in line with the practice given in a widely-used [successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

---

If, in terms of how your team interprets commits, leaving the origins of that common content recorded only in the text of commit messages is preferable, git's got that covered too. Instead of recording the ancestry permanently, via the checkouts and merges after the `base` assignment above, you can also

```
echo $(git rev-parse master  master~)  $base > .git/info/grafts
echo $(git rev-parse develop develop~) $base >>.git/info/grafts
git checkout master
git merge develop

# later, whenever you want -- the ancestry above is strictly repo-local
rm .git/info/grafts
```

Ancestry recorded in `.git/info/grafts` is repo-local.  Your merge commands will see it, and the result will be correct.  The only downside to this is since the base isn't actually recorded others will have the same trouble repeating it -- very unlikely unless you're doing [criss-cross merges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Recursive_three-way_merge) or also cherrypicking to other branches.

Answer (score 0):

With git-cherry-pick there's not a good way to avoid the merge conflict that will happen with the topic with the picked changes merges with master (where the changes were picked to).

I recommend that you perform the cherry-pick operation, then do a test merge locally and discover if the conflicts are something Git cannot manage without user intervention before you worry about avoiding the conflicts.

One of the tricks I tend to do to mimic partial cherry-picks is:

```
git cherry-pick <commitish>
git checkout HEAD~ -- <path of unwanted change in file>
git checkout HEAD~ -- <path of unwanted change in file>
git checkout HEAD~ -- <path of unwanted change in file>
git checkout HEAD~ -- <path of unwanted change in file>
git commit -am "squash me"
git rebase -i HEAD~~
```

The squash the cherry-pick and checkout/revert together.