# How can I split a previous git commit into separate commits?

Tags: git

I'm trying to track down an error that was introduced somewhere in a certain commit. Unfortunately, that commit consists of a lot of files and I'm not sure where the problem arose. I'd like to do something like "git bisect", but that would only help if I could split the problem commit into a bunch of smaller commits.

I don't have any problem with creating a branch, reverting the problem commit, then re-applying it as a series of commits, but I don't know how to do that. Researching this question here on Stack Overflow results in a lot of answers related to rewriting the history (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6217156/2008384) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4307095/2008384)), which I don't want to do because the commit in question happened in the past and it's been pushed to a central repository.

**How can I split a single commit modifying multiple files into a series of commits, one for each file?**

Edit: maybe I haven't explained the question clearly enough.

I have a repository with commits that look like this

```
A --- B --- C --- D
```

Commit B is a problem. A bug was introduced and it's been narrowed down to commit B. But commit B consists of a large number of changes to a large number of files, so it's unclear exactly what caused the bug.

What I'd like to do is this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- revert B --- B1 --- B2  --- ... --- Bn
```

Where `B1`, `B2`, ... `Bn` are commits of the individual files that were changed in commit B.

If I can get the problematic commit broken down, I can then use `git bisect` to narrow down the problem further.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: My recommendation here is to just fix the bug, and apply the patch.  Rewriting the history of a published branch has all sorts of negative caveats associated with it, not to mention that doing what you want would require quite a bit of Git olympics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you already know which commit introduced the error and is just trying to use git to help you understand more about the code:

**1.) Create a branch on the commit you want to investigate**

e.g. `git branch investigation abcdef1` (where `abcdef1` is the hash or the problematic commit)

ps: `investigation` is just a name I chose for the branch... Can be something else...

---

**2.) Go to the new branch you've just created**

e.g. `git checkout investigation`

---

**3.) Undo the problematic commit** (only affects this new branch, so no damage to the original history in your main branch)

e.g. `git reset HEAD~1`

At this point, all the files that were added/changed/deleted will be back to their original state just before the commit was done. You can do a `git status` to see all the differences.

From here, you can start creating the commits as you wish, either one by file, or grouping some of them... It's up to you.

---

Of course, this is just for you to track down where the bug is... You would not merge this branch back to `master` or anything like that... It's just a throwaway branch for the purposes of investigating the bug... Once you know where the bug is, go back to `master` (or whatever branch is your trunk one) and fix the bug there, and then just delete the `investigation` branch.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! It seems like a bit of a hack to use `git reset` in this way, but it should work. Thanks very much, I'll give it a try.