# Split commit into existing commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

I have a branch with several commits:

```
A --- B --- C --- D
                  ^
                 HEAD
```

I have finished to work on this branch and preparing the pull request. But I am not satisfied with the current history:

- C is modifying a lot files that would have been better to commit into A and B
- D is fixing some independent issues and should be kept as

I am looking for a clean way to split C into A and B without breaking D.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split up a Git commit buried in history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307095/how-can-i-split-up-a-git-commit-buried-in-history)

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio Partially but I don't want to split C into 2 new commits, I want to move the changes commited in C into commits A and B.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to rebase twice:

- First, run interactive rebase with `git rebase -i HEAD^4`
- In the editor window, find the commit that you want to split and replace the first word `pick` with `e` (short for `edit`)
- Save and exit editor, the rebase will get you after the commit you set for editing
- Reset the commit with `git reset HEAD~`
- Now your changes are unstaged and you can commit them as you wish
- Using `git add -p` can be useful to add only some changes in a file
- Create two commits, one to be merged in A and the other to be merged in B
- `git rebase --continue`

Now, you've split your commit into two, the history should look like that:

```
A --- B --- Ca --- Cb --- D
                          ^
                        HEAD
```

You can now start the second rebase to merge `Ca` into `A` and `Cb` into `B`:

- `git rebase -i HEAD^4`
- In the editor, move the line of the commit `Ca` under the line of the commit `A` and change `pick` to `s` (short for `squash`).
- Move the line of `Cb` under the line of the commit `B` and also set it to squash into `B`
- `git rebase --continue`

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `temp` branch on C that I will play with, let's suppose that main is on D (not specified, but):

```
git branch -b temp C
# let's go back to A, keeping _all_ of C's content so you can decide what to keep:
git reset --soft A
# now get the files the way you would like to get it for A (you can compare with A and B, just so that you _really_ get what you want.
# when you are done
git commit -m "new A"
# temp is on the new A

# let's go back to C
git checkout C
# let's put it on top of temp
git reset --soft temp
# Get the files you want the to be on B (compare with HEAD~1 and B.. and C)
# when you are done
git commit -m "new B"
# let's put temp where we are
git branch -f temp

# finally, let's move whatever is left over from C that is not part of B
git checkout C
git reset --soft temp
git commit -m "New C"
git branch -f temp
# at this moment C and temp are exactly the same

git checkout temp
git cherry-pick D
# temp is like the branch you want
```

... and that's it.

*If* actually C is what you would like B to be like, with some changes on A, then follow the recipe about "new A", then

```
git checkout C
git reset --soft temp
git commit -m "New B"
git branch -f temp
git checkout temp
git cherry-pick D
```