# Break up multiple changes into separate commits with git?

Tags: git

If I have made multiple sets of changes to a large file, is it possible to split those into separate commits using git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a commit into smaller commits with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118042/how-to-split-a-commit-into-smaller-commits-with-git).

Comment: Also, it's not clear if the changes have already been committed or not. If they've been committed in several commits already, `rebase --interactive` is the way to go. If not, `git add --patch` is one of the options you should consider.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You want `git add --patch` ([documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-patch)), which will allow you to select which changes to stage.

Comment: Why the downvote?  git add -i is overkill if all you want is to select hunks, since the first option you'll pick from the -i menu is 'p' (or 5), so you might as well have jumped straight to it with --patch.

Comment: Really, another downvote with no explanation?  If you believe there is something wrong with `git add --patch`, please have the courtesy to provide an explanation as to why.

Comment: I think the downvotes (not from me!) are from folk who have already committed, where this answer won't work. The question doesn't say whether the changes are committed or not.

Comment: Short form to this is `git add -p` which allows us to select which hunk to stage

Comment: @mikemaccana the question does not say that the files are commited. I updated this answer.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can -- use `git add -i` to select which hunks you want to stage for each commit.  You can get documentation by running `git help add` and scrolling to "Interactive Mode".

Answer (score 1):

One more option which I constantly use is just because i forget about the `patch` option :):

Say you have updated files: `aaa.txt`, `bbb.txt`, `ccc.txt` and you want to `push` the `aaa.txt` file in the first commit and then `bbb.txt` and `ccc.txt` in the second commit:

```
step 1:
--------------------
git add aaa.txt
git commit -m "Added first file"
git stash
git push

step 2:
--------------------
git stash pop
git add -A
git commit -m "Added the rest of the modified data"
git push
```

Might be a little more verbose, but in my opinion I it gives a bit more control.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Williams answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948806/1106393) is perfectly valid. But sometimes it is easier to do things by hand. For example if you accidentally updated some third-party library with a lot of files before committing the changes you previously made. With `git add -p` (same as `--patch`) you would need to walk through all of this files. So in this case it is much more convenient to just stage the file you want to commit and do a second commit with all of the other changes:

```
> git add /path/to/your/file.txt
> git commit -m "my commit message"
[master a0c5ea6] my commit message
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
> git add --all
> git commit -m "updated library xyz"
```

Comment: Actually, `git add -p` allows you to select the particular file at the command line, and within the interactive session you can jump to a particular hunk using `g`, or search for a hunk matching a regex using  `/`.  The point of `add -p` is to select hunks from a file, but this proposed solution requires adding the entire file, which is not what the OP wants.