# Splitting git commit into a few commits

Tags: git

I have fixed two bugs in a piece of code, and it modifies common files. For example, bug fix 1 modified file A, B, C, and bug fix 2 modified B, C, and D. I have all changes in one commit. For the purpose of code reviews, I need to split the changes into two commits (two branches actually).

What I am thinking is that from my current branch `fix`, I create two branches like `git branch fix-1 fix` and `git branch fix-2 fix`. Both branches have all changes. Now, in branch `fix-1`, I would like to keep the changes relevant to fix 1 only, that is, all changes in file A, and parts of changes in files B and C. Is it possible to do it in git? What command is relevant for this?

I know that in `git add`, I can do interactive add where I can select hunks of code for adding, not just at file level. Is there something similar I can do here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a commit into smaller commits with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118042/how-to-split-a-commit-into-smaller-commits-with-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the commit was your last commit, here is a solution.

1. Checkout the branch with the fix

   ```
   git checkout fix
   ```
2. Reset back to before the fixes, but keep the changes in your working dir

   ```
   git reset HEAD^
   ```
3. Create branch for fix-1

   ```
   git checkout -b fix-1
   ```
4. Add/commit fix-1 fixes

   ```
   git add -p
   git commit
   ```
5. Stash the remaining changes

   ```
   git stash
   ```
6. Checkout/create branch for fix-2

   ```
   git checkout -b fix-1
   ```
7. Pop off your stashed changes

   ```
   git stash pop
   ```
8. Commit/add them

   ```
   git commit -a
   ```

Comment: I think the second command should be `git reset --mixed HEAD^`. This solution worked very well for me. Thanks.

Comment: Correct:) edited to show correction.  It will default to --mixed when no flag is given.

Comment: I used that combining it with `git rebase -i HEAD~X`, to move forward the commit I wanted to split.

Where X was the number of commits back to reorder to bring forward the target commit.

Answer (score 3):

From the state you're in (two branches, each with all changes) go into each branch and do `git rebase -i fix^` and select "edit" for the `fix` commit.  Then when it pauses for you to edit the commit you use `git reset HEAD^` which throws away the commit but leaves the changes in the working tree.  Then use your usual `git add -p` strategy to split up the commit into multiple `git commits` and then `git rebase --continue`.

I think this is in the `git rebase` manual under `SPLITTING COMMITS`.

Comment: After doing `git add -p`, I do `git commit`, but after that, doing `git rebase --continue` results in 
    /path/to/file1.txt: needs update
    /path/to/file2.txt: needs update
    Working tree is dirty
and I stay in `(no branch)`. Cannot figure out what to do after that. What I did was to `git stash` and it threw away changes and I came back to the original branch. Any ideas what I should do after `git commit` when I get `Working tree is dirty`.

Comment: Oh, right, since you don't want all of the changes you will want to `git reset --hard` to discard all the working copy edit after you commit the parts you want.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This solution works well, but the solution by Andy above is simpler and I understand better what is going on. My understanding is on shaky ground whenever git starts to show `(no branch)`, and this solution involves going into `(no branch)` mode! :-) Thanks for suggesting the solution.

Comment: I like @Andy's answer too although you'd need a solution more like mine if you had committed additional changes past the commit you need to split.

Comment: Agreed. I happened to have any commits after the commit I wanted to split.