# recommit a portion of commit (by line numbers) to another commit in git

Tags: git, commit

Suppose I've committed a whole bunch of lines in a whole bunch of files as commit A with the message "Commit A"

Suppose I want to recommit a portion of commit A (by line numbers) as a new commit with the message "Commit B"

How do I achieve this in git? (Moreover, the portion of the commit I'm trying to recommit are identified by line numbers and there are other lines in the same file that I don't want to recommit)

Comment: The answer depends on whatever the common ancester of commitA and commitB are. If files are the same for that ancester, then there is a solution.

Comment: Are you trying to ***split*** `A` into two separate commits? Are they in the same branch, or did you want `B` to go into a separate branch? Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a commit into smaller commits with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118042/how-to-split-a-commit-into-smaller-commits-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking, but I'm assuming you want to split a commit into two commits.  If so, you can use an interactive rebase to do this.  See the section "Splitting Commits" in `git help rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to commit *most* of the lines, the easier route might be `git cherry-pick --no-commit` followed by appropriate editing before you `git commit`. However, if the portion you want to commit is on the smaller end, a `git rebase -i` to separate the desired changes from the undesired ones, before doing a `git cherry-pick`, would probably be easier. If you definitely want to leave the original commit the way it is, make sure to create a temporary branch first.